# What is the best way to redirect users where there are admins and regular users?

Tags: php, html, mysql, redirect

I have a CMS environment where there are administrator users and I need a way to redirect users who are either not administrators or do not own the document they're trying to edit. It looks something like this, but my administrators cannot access the page this way and Im unsure why:

```
$cannotpass=0;
if ($reportsusername != $usersusername) {
    $cannotpass++;
}

if ($usersadmin != $admin) {
    $cannotpass++;
}   

if ($cannotpass >= 1) {
    header("location:http://decibeldesignstudios.com/blackbirdsecurity/adminlanding");  
}
```

Comment: Any of the answers solve the question or helped at all? What isn't working the way you'd like it to? Is anything working at all? The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a counter?

You can simplify it as follows:

```
if ($reportsusername != $usersusername && $usersadmin != $admin) {
    header("location:http://decibeldesignstudios.com/blackbirdsecurity/adminlanding");  
}
```